# passenger with SSE (server sent events)

Tags: nginx, redis, passenger, server-sent-events

I have a local development server which is running on apache2 and redis and I use thin for SSE events. All is working perfect.

Once I deploy with Mina to the production server (nginx, redis) the clients are not subscribing to the channel. I use https://github.com/madchatter/mad_chatter/ with my current app.

This means that the messages are not reloaded/refreshed automatically and only on page refresh.

From the network connections I can see that:

subscribe
/chat/protocols/sse/rooms/1
GET (canceled) 1:1

after about 1 min of pending state. I can see the subscription request in Redis CLI but nothing happens.

Anybody has some idea what I am missing?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using a recent enough version of Phusion Passenger? The latest version is 4.0.50. Versions earlier than ~4.0.5 (or something) have problems with WebSockets/SSE.

Comment: I tried to upgrade with sudo apt-get update (remained on 4.0.45) and then I downloaded the source from Github but the installer it says 4.0.50 - where can I get 4.0.51?

Comment: Oops, I meant 4.0.50, sorry.